# Personalization Builder: In depth description of import status

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-recommendations

When importing a catalogue (Marketing Cloud / Personalization Builder / Email Recommendations) I typically get a valid status because of duplicates. But I can find no description of how these duplicates are handled. Ie. are all duplicates skipped?

I know of this page:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_catalog_import_status.htm&type=5

but I'd like an indepth description to at least the valid status.
Can anyone help?

Thank you :)

Comment: The question rather is: Why do you have duplicates? Why don't you get rid of them? Is your catalog designed correctly? That are the questions you have to ask yourself. A catalog with duplicates feels very bad when you have web tracking referring to them. It may totally destroy scenarios or user profiles. Rather ask how can i solve the problem rather than what happens when i have the problem.

Comment: You're right. We're continously working on fixing these issues. But as we import several catalogues to more than 70 markets, it's hard for us to make sure catalogues are always without duplicates, meaning that sometimes we'll have to accept a staus of valid (imported with duplicates) rather than success (imported without success).. In those scenarios I'd like to know how duplicates are handled and how it impacts us until we have been able to investigate why we'll have duplicates and being able to fix it :)

Comment: In that case you need a single source of truth (SSOT) as kind of a table / database whatever. In this catalog you could also have a flag to which market the product belongs to. It should be a company decision to clarify this. You really need to have something like an SSOT in place.

Comment: The catalog is not imported when they are duplicates present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The in-depth description is that you tried to upload a catalog in the correct format but has other errors, in this case Duplicate SKUID. When this occurs the catalog is not imported into the system and no values were updated for any items.

You would need to ensure you catalog had no duplicate values for SKUID and you receive a "Success" status

Comment: Thanks. The Valid status confused me. As you describe it, it's actually not imported at all. I had this similar answer back from an ask the expert session: "SKUID, is a primarykey field (unique value), and can't not be duplicated in the catalog. If the catalog has duplicate SKUID, the import will fail and nothing will be imported, and an error would be surfaced in the UI for this issue." ... thank you